# Python requests module not posting to certain input fields

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I'm trying to data scrape from a website behind a login screen, and I've run into a problem with posting parts of the login info with the post() method from python's requests module.

I've gotten the names of each HTML input field that needs to be filled in and placed them in a dictionary along with their required value, and then passed that dictionary to the post() method.

The HTML from the login page:

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBox1" type="text" value="" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox1" tabindex="1" class="form-control " placeholder="username" required="">
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBox2" type="password" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox2" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="password" required="" value="">
```

Then, using the name value to create the dictionary that's passed to post()

```
formData = { 
    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBox1": "FakeUsername",            
    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBox2": "FakePassword"
    }

r = session.get(loginUrl)  # get cookies necessary for login
r = session.post(loginUrl, data=formData)
```

This works properly for the username field, but it does not post the password in the password field. If I read the HTML from the login page after posting the data, I get:

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBox1" type="text" value="FakeUsername" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox1" tabindex="1" class="form-control " placeholder="username" required="" />
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBox2" type="password" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox2" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="password" required="" />
```

The "value" parameter of the password input field is no longer listed, not even as an empty parameter. Attempting a login after this of course does not work.

I have been unable to figure out why this is happening. I've made sure to fill in any hidden input fields (EVENTVALIDATION, VIEWSTATE, etc.) and have also 
looked at the webpage headers, but have still had no luck.

The website I'm trying to log in to is:
https://panel.forcad.org/Default.aspx

I would really appreciate help figuring out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You said you looked at the headers, but you should be able to replicate the browser behavior with request headers and cookies. Try copying the exact params for and cookies on a known successful login. So you can narrow it down if you can even use requests to send the data it already wants. Maybe it has some JS tricks, or does some stuff requests can not do, if you can't re-login with valid cookies. In that case, more reverse engineeering, or try selenium. pyvirtualdisplay can hide the browser and can use JS to stop() loading of the page